# Android Amazon Rekognition Text Detection doesn't work with bytes but does with S3 Objects

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rekognition

I'm trying to detect text in a photo taken with the Camera, but with no luck.

The code I'm using is:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new AWSCredentials() {
            @Override
            public String getAWSAccessKeyId() {
                return "some access key id";
            }

            @Override
            public String getAWSSecretKey() {
                return "some secret key";
            }
        };


        File file = new File(photoFilePath);
        int size = (int) file.length();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        try {
            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            buf.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Timber.e(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Timber.e(e);
        }

        AmazonRekognition rekognitionClient = new AmazonRekognitionClient(credentials);

        byte [] base64 = android.util.Base64.encode(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Image image = new Image().withBytes(ByteBuffer.wrap(base64));

        DetectTextRequest detectTextRequest = new DetectTextRequest().withImage(image);

        Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<String>) observer -> {
            try {
                DetectTextResult result = rekognitionClient.detectText(detectTextRequest);
                List<TextDetection> labels = result.getTextDetections();

                String alllabels = "";

                for (TextDetection detection : labels) {
                    alllabels += detection.getDetectedText();
                }

                observer.onNext(alllabels);
                observer.onCompleted();
            } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                Timber.e(e);
                observer.onError(e);
            } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
                Timber.e(e);
                observer.onError(e);
            }
        })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onNext(String item) {
                System.out.println("Next: " + item);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable error) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                System.out.println("Sequence complete.");
            }
        });
    }
```

This produces an exception with the message

```
Failed to upload image; the format is not supported
```

When not encoding the bytes in base64 - it yields weird outputs, where each text detected is separated by a comma, like

> S, !!:, 8, anons SAr, !!:, S, 8, anons, SAr,

or

> 8B, 8B

What might be wrong in with my example?

When using references to S3 Objects even with the same photo - everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image was rotated and it's why it returned weird data...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the server is rejecting your request due to unsupported formats. Please note that AWS Rekognition only supports the PNG and JPEG Image formats, and has specific requirements on pixel resolution etc [See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/limits.html for more information on the image requirements]

I have had success in the past with jpg images using the following code

```
InputStream fin1 = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier("face1", "raw", getPackageName()));
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(fin1));

    Image image1 = new Image();
    image1.withBytes(byteBuffer1);
```

Please try it out and let me know if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but I found out it didn't work because the image was rotated.. :)